# getting error selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH in python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm getting the following error for selenium in python.
I've installed selenium by **pip install selenium** and then extracted selenium file to **C:\Program Files\Python36**.

Here is my script:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
dir = os.path.dirname('C:\chromedriver_win32')
chrome_driver_path = dir + "\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
search_field = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search_field.send_keys("Selenium WebDriver Interview questions")
search_field.submit()
lists= driver.find_elements_by_class_name("r")
print ("Found " + str(len(lists)) + " searches:")
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to set PATH to include `C:\chromedriver_win32`
But I suggest you to put `chromedriver.exe` in the same directory of your `python.exe`.
[set PATH](https://www.google.com/search?q=set%20path&ncr&cad=h)

As for your own code, might as well just use one line instead:

```
chrome_driver_path = 'C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe'
```

There's no need to import and use `os`.

Also note that `os` or not, you should escape `\` itself.
Eg:

```
>>> os.path.dirname('C:\chromedriver_win32')
'C:\\'
>>> os.path.dirname('C:\\chromedriver_win32\\')
'C:\\chromedriver_win32'
```

Comment: already set C:\chromedriver_win32 in environment variable and tried also keeping in the same directory where python.exe is located.

Comment: @fakhrul  Check updated part. However I suggest you put chromedriver in python's dir. And delete chrome_driver_path when initiate driver.

Comment: @fakhrul  Sorry I made a mistake, updated again.